# Determine which files have change in branch as an azure build step

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to determine which files have changed in the branch that I am building in my Azure pipelines.

I know I can do this using a powershell script with git.

I have roughly this powershell script "determine-builds.ps1"

```
$files = $(git diff origin/$targetBranch...origin/$currentBranch --name-only)
$fileList = $files -split ' '

# loop through file list and determine if front end or back end files have changed

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=frontEndChanged;isOutput=true]$frontEndChanged"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backEndChanged;isOutput=true]$backEndChanged"
```

I am calling the script like this in my build yaml file:

```
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: "Determine builds"
          inputs:
            targetType: 'filePath'
            filePath: pipelines/determine-builds.ps1
            arguments: -targetBranch $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch) -currentBranch $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)
```

My powershell script works great locally. But the problem is that when it runs in the pipeline the `git diff` command fails with this error: `unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. Because git is only doing a fetching rather than a full clone, it isn't aware of my feature branch name.

What should the git command be to acheive this?

Comment: Add `origin` name to => `$files = $(git diff origin/$targetBranch --name-only)`

Comment: This is much better thank you.! Is there a way I could compare it to the target branch I branched from? i.e., the 3 dot diff? (https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_diff_dots.html)

Comment: did you try `git diff main..origin/$targetBranch`

Comment: Note that diffing since the merge-base (3 dots) tells you what was changed on the branch, but not necessarily what *will* change once it's merged. (Imagine the scenario where some of the changes were implemented on both branches.) The only way to know for sure what *will* change, is if the branch is fully up to date, or if you do a temporary merge and look at it.

Comment: `git diff master...origin/master --name-only` (master is target branch) shows all the diffs between what I have now and what is currently on master. I want the diff from what I have now from when I branched from master.